There's a splash of light that appears on the upper portion part of my screen, is my laptop screen broken?
There's a small portion on the upper part of the screen that emits light

I enhanced the photo a lot and could see some backlight bleeding. Is that perhaps what you are referring to?

Yes sir, and I got nervous thinking that my laptop screen has a problem

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

That is called blacklight bleeding, and it's common on LCD IPS displays, specially high refresh rate ones. I'm yet to encounter one that doesn't suffer, at least a little, from that problem. The only real solution is to get an OLED screen (impossible in the case of a laptop, as the screen assembly is specific to your laptop, and you can't change the display technology). They also tend to be much more expensive.

The backlight bleed doesn't look too serious from the photo. In any case, it is not something that is damaging to the laptop. As long as it doesn't hinder you, there's not really a need to get it fixed. If your laptop is still within warranty, you could see if you can get it fixed for free, but its definitely not worth spending money on to get it fixed otherwise.

@John What a weird response. If someone posts an image of a car with a little scratch on it, will you also tell them to get it fixed? And yes, I am aware that if the scratch goes all the way through the paint, it may cause rust, but even then, I would not state: you must get it fixed asap, but rather explain what it is and that it might be a good idea.
